# Mess with permission files

Tags: permissions, chmod

i've written `chmod 755 /etc/` and `chmod 0644 /etc/` and now i find myself without access to anything,and inside the terminal where before there was `username@system1:` now there's `I have no name!@system1:` . I know i messed everything up,but there's a solution? a way to restore the default configuration? I Cannot reinstall,so i've to repair..

Comment: If you can't login as root, boot into singe user mode and fix it, otherwise use a live cd to fix it. I guess you've locked yourself out, since the `passwd` file resides in `/etc`.

Comment: Ok,how i enter in single user mode and how i fix the mess when i'm inside the system as single user?

Comment: First entry of a web search: [Boot Linux Grub Into Single User Mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/). Even it's old it still should work.

Comment: Ok then,when i'm inside the system,what can i do to fix the mess?

Comment: What system do you run? Linux?

Comment: Yes,debian 7 "Wheezy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming you are running Linux with Grub as bootloader:*

1. Boot into [Boot Linux Grub Into Single User Mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/)
2. Login with the root account
3. Execute `chmod 755 /etc`
4. Reboot the system

I'm not sure if you can go beyond point 2. If it's not possible to login as root (which in fact should be, since the process which asks you for your password should have access to the `/etc` directory since it runs with uid 1) you need to boot from a live CD to execute step 3:

1. Boot from live CD
2. Mount the root file system of your operative UNIX system
3. Change the permissions of `/etc` back to `755`

Comment: ok...i tried to enter as root,or in single user mod but that wasn't possible(black blank screen or a black screen with the cursor in a never-ending loading)  so i tried to boot with live cd and also that DIDN'T WORK. I change the boot priority(first the cd,than at the second slot the hd) but the boot go on as i never inserted any cd...i'm really afraid that i mess badly with the sysstem...

Comment: That you cannot boot from your CD is for sure not related with the messed permissions.

Comment: Ok,i'm an idiot...the CD reader was half unplugged. However ,having Debian live cd,where i go to mount the root file system? i'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: It strongly depends on your setting: Do you use LVM? Do you use mdadm? Plain partition?

Comment: I've all the file in one partition(the default configuration)...the CD i'm using is the one from which i installed Debian.

Comment: Try `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. If that works, you should see the `/etc` directory of your faulty installation in `/mnt/etc`. If that does not work, maybe printing `fdisk -l /dev/sd*` might help to determine your setting.